# Can I use a class method inside an Android View?

Tags: java, android, class, view

I'm new to Android(Java), and one of my lessons is to create this scenario.
[image]

They teach to use a different method for each button, but that adds two methods almost equal and my DRY mind says it's not the best solution.

Sho I wrote a `BasketTeam` class:

```
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BasketTeam {

    private TextView team;

    public BasketTeam(View v) {
        team = (TextView) v;
    }

    public void threePointsThrow(View v) {
        this.addPoints(3);
    }

    public void twoPointsThrow(View v) {
        addPoints(2);
    }

    public void freeThrow(View v) {
        addPoints(1);
    }

    private void addPoints(Integer addedScore) {
        Integer teamScore = Integer.parseInt((String) team.getText());
        team.setText("" + (teamScore + addedScore));
    }

    public void resetScore() {
        team.setText("" + 0);
    }
}
```

And at my MainActivity I've created 2 instances as public `BasketTeam1` and `BasketTeam2`.
They are both okay and well instanced since in my MainActivity I have a method called `resetScore` use them and it works:

```
public void resetScore(View v) {
    BasketTeam1.resetScore();
    BasketTeam2.resetScore();
}
```

But when I try to use one of those class methods in my view, it can't find.
Why?

Here is a example of my try:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:text="+3 points"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/team_1_3_points"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:onClick="BasketTeam1.threePointsThrow"/>
```

**Update**

This is the error message:

> 05-25 13:30:19.880 2345-2345/com.example.android.courtcounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.android.courtcounter, PID: 2345
>                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method BasketTeam1.threePointsThrow(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'team_1_3_points'

Comment: I think you need to post your View code.

Comment: Kind of peculiar that you actually save the score in the textview. My MVC-Mind tells me it would be better to save the data in the model and update the view on change ... Another point: Why do you pass a View to your `xxxPointsThrow` Methods? You do not seem to use it ...

Comment: Nevermind the last part of my above comment. They are onClickHandlers ...

Comment: View code now showing. Didn't put enough spaces.
@Fildor I'm new at Java and Android, I just modified the code from the tutorial, to try an better approach.

Comment: Can you add the exact errormessage you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onClick` property of your Button must correspond to a method in the Button's Context, typically your `MainActivity`. See [onClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick).

A solution may be:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void threePointsThrow(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.team_1_3_points:
                basketTeam1.threePointsThrow();
                break;
            case R.id.team_2_3_points:
                basketTeam2.threePointsThrow();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the layout:

```
<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:text="+3 points"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:id="@+id/team_1_3_points"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:onClick="threePointsThrow"/>
```